# Google API Invalid grant on one-time auth code from GoogleAuthUtil.getToken

Tags: android, google-api, oauth-2.0

I'm using GoogleAuthUtil.getToken() to get a one-time code in an Android app, which is then sent to our server. Our server then exchanges this for an access token, and uses this to get the users e-mail.

This seems to work. But, if I do the following:

1. Get the one-time code
2. Send it to server
3. Consume it, and authenticate the user
4. Wipe Android app data (making it forget the authentication
5. Get the one-time code

The second one-time code is actually identical to the first.

This has now already been consumed once, so the server gets the following error when trying to exchange it for an access token the second time:

```
Error:"invalid_grant", Description:"Invalid code.[Email: 
Token Record:
Token: "4/aQQ_nbklfajrilawjvlkasjvVMD.AMsaNNC-gdsai3gJDIAvajvkrelwiDDI"
IssueDomain: "123456789012-1231231564adsafdas1f23a45fd6sad2.apps.googleusercontent.com"
IssueTimeSec: 1387110988
ExpirationTime: 1387111588
TokenUsage: 3
Scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"
Scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
Scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.moments.write"
Scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me"
Scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.agerange.read"
Scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.language.read"
Scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.members.read"
ServiceInfo {
 ServiceId: 123
 Info <
   [13245678] <
     0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05 0x06 0x07 0x08 0x09 0x0a 
   >
 >
}
ServiceInfo {
 ServiceId: 226
 Info <
   [security_lso_auth_oauth2.EarlyIssuedTokenProto] <
     auto_approved: false
     access_token: "fd12.a.Afdsa1eawfdsa2avi_f1ds2af15eaw61f2ag45a6v8-1f3ds2af5ew6a12-ad5A"
     refresh_token: "2/da4ge5a4f5dsav-fsa54fe4wa5f_dfasenU-dsaddew"
   >
 >
}
Revoked: true
AuthorizedBy: 0x1234567890
OAuthCallbackUrl: "urn:accounts.google.com:api_auth:programmatic:virtual_redirect_uri"
OfflineAccess: true
RevokeOnPasswordChange: true
ClientManagedRevocation: false
InBundle: true
]", Uri:""
```

(sensitive data is replaced with random values)

I see the ExpirationTime has not yet been reached (10 minutes validity), but shouldn't a one-time code be returned only once from GoogleAuthUtil.getToken()?

This may not be an issue in a deployment situation, since most users would only log in once, so is this by design? Should I handle it in any way on the server, or just accept that this will occur?

Comment: See comment #2 to answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18959880/is-googleauthutil-gettoken-thread-safe not sure what his source is, though.

Comment: Thanks. Seems to be the case, that it is cached. A bit strange, perhaps, as the server cannot accept this token a second time, in any case.

Comment: You server should return a nice error to the client that says: "Wait a  bit and try again, you're going too fast..." for the rare case where the client is installed twice within 10 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Seems using GoogleAuthUtil.invalidateToken(context, token) can invalidate the token. You can then request a new token by calling getToken() next time. But this requires to add user permission android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS.