# grant_error invalid code in android-GAE

Tags: android, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0

I am currently following the instructions given [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/CrossClientAuth) for cross-client validation in an Android-GAE app, so my users can give the Python backend off-line access to the G+ APIs on their behalf. That documentation also directs me [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#handlingtheresponse), which is really where I am having the trouble. I have successfully obtained an authorization code and sent it to the backend, but when the backend tries to exchange that code for access and refresh tokens I get "error:invalid_grant" with "error description: invalid code". To illustrate, when I copy the code and other needed info into a curl, the output is as follows:

```
curl -d "code=4/uG6moqbHvs9hgfG1HmEfT39zT1j0.Un-H_36OXGUWmmS0T3UFEsMwQpwOhwI&client_secret={MY_SECRET}&client_id={MY_WEB_CLIENT_ID}&grant_type=authorization_code" https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token -v
* Adding handle: conn: 0x7fc359803a00
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7fc359803a00) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to accounts.google.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 74.125.28.84...
* Connected to accounts.google.com (74.125.28.84) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
* Server certificate: accounts.google.com
* Server certificate: Google Internet Authority G2
* Server certificate: GeoTrust Global CA
* Server certificate: Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
> POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: accounts.google.com
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 219
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* upload completely sent off: 219 out of 219 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
< Date: Sun, 12 Jan 2014 16:38:42 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
* Server GSE is not blacklisted
< Server: GSE
< Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< 
{
  "error" : "invalid_grant",
  "error_description" : "Invalid code.[Email: \n\nToken Record:\nToken: \"4/uG6moqbHvs9hgfG1HmEfT39zT1j0.Un-H_36OXGUWmmS0T3UFEsMwQpwOhwI\"\nIssueDomain: \"206701529154-7d35h3g4a22aef8d78p6up1cdiq3pl4d.apps.googleusercontent.com\"\nIssueTimeSec: 1389544361\nExpirationTime: 1389544961\nTokenUsage: 3\nScope: \"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login\"\nScope: \"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile\"\nScope: \"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email\"\nScope: \"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.moments.write\"\nScope: \"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me\"\nScope: \"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.agerange.read\"\nScope: \"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.language.read\"\nScope: \"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.circles.members.read\"\nServiceInfo {\n  ServiceId: 226\n  Info <\n    [security_lso_auth_oauth2.EarlyIssuedTokenProto] <\n      auto_approved: false\n      access_token: \"ya29.1.AADtN_UyJ2wiWB7lh7btUiCwUyHzix_DrubjdSsTxA6drG-ZccPWaeZJa31sebPnRCHiFw\"\n      refresh_token: \"1/ImSjHYLkFcBOwsCezBg2dKpcqko9by3nTIh_k33ZMds\"\n    >\n  >\n}\nRevoked: true\nAuthorizedBy: 0x866419b291\nOAuthCallbackUrl: \"urn:accounts.google.com:api_auth:programmatic:virtual_redirect_uri\"\nOfflineAccess: true\nRevokeOnPasswordChange: true\nClientManagedRevocation: false\nInBundle: true\n]"
* Connection #0 to host accounts.google.com left intact
}%
```

I'm having a lot of trouble making sense of this error message to determine why my authorization code might be invalid. I did notice that in the explorer logs, all logs are time-stamped an hour in the past (so when I post a log at 11AM, it appears in the explorer with a timestamp of 10AM). Could a timezone discrepancy somehow be causing the oauth2 servers to think I am submitting authorization codes that are too old? I already tried changing my system time to match the log time, to no avail. Does anyone know what could be causing my authorization code to be invalid? I have searched high and low for hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortly after posting this question, I discovered the answer myself. Posting it here in case others run into the same problem. I noticed that a similar error was occurring in [Google API Invalid grant on one-time auth code from GoogleAuthUtil.getToken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20594822/google-api-invalid-grant-on-one-time-auth-code-from-googleauthutil-gettoken?rq=1), and the reason was that the developer needed to request refresh/access tokens multiple times within the span of 10 minutes (which is the expiration duration of the one-time authorization code). Inspecting my explorer logs again, I saw that I have a bug in my android code causing my cross-client validation code to be run twice in rapid succession instead of only once like it's supposed to. The first time it's run, the refresh and access tokens are returned correctly. The second time, the error is generated.

In retrospect, the "revoked = True" part of the error message should have pointed me to the answer.

Comment: but what if in a scenario i want to get token in quick succession ? And i have invalidatd the generated token using GoogleAuthUtil.invalidateToken(this, code); manually . then too i get the same error.